# Problems in using STIX Math with xelatex and lualatex

Tags: xetex, luatex

This MWE compiles fine in lualatex and xelatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{unicode-maths}
   \setmainfont{STIX}
    \setmathfont{STIX Math Regular}
  \newfontface{\chaptitlefont}{STIX-Bold}[Scale=1.6]
  \newfontface{\sectionfont}{STIX-Bold}[Scale=1.4]
  \newfontface{\subsectionfont}{STIX-Bold}[Scale=1.2]
  \setmonofont{InconsolataN}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
    This is a test.\\
    {\chaptitlefont Chapter title}\\
    {\sectionfont Section font}\\
    \(
    \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1
    \)\\
    \(\mathbf{x^2+y^2=1}\).\\
\verb|Where|
\end{document}
```

It gives the following warning message.

```
Package unicode-math Warning: The first font loaded by unicode-math must be an
(unicode-math)                OpenType Math font (with script=math). If you
(unicode-math)                simply want ‘the default’ before loading
(unicode-math)                supplementary fonts over the top for certain
(unicode-math)                ranges, use: 
(unicode-math)                  \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
```

Instead of using STIX Math, it uses latinmorder-math.otf as can be seen at the end of the log file produced by lulatex:

```
<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/inconsolata/InconsolataN-Regul
ar.otf><c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Bold.otf><c:/
texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/latinmodern-math.otf><c:/t
exlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/latinmodern-math.otf><c:/te
xlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Regular.otf><c:/texlive/20
20/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Bold.otf><c:/texlive/2020/texmf-di
st/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Regular.otf>
```

It shows warning about STIX Math:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "STIXMathRegular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Math".
```

If I set math font as latinmodern-math before STIX Math, as in the following MWE, it compiles OK.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
   \setmainfont{STIX}
     \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
   \setmathfont{STIX Math Regular}
  \newfontface{\chaptitlefont}{STIX-Bold}[Scale=1.6]
  \newfontface{\sectionfont}{STIX-Bold}[Scale=1.4]
  \newfontface{\subsectionfont}{STIX-Bold}[Scale=1.2]
  \setmonofont{InconsolataN}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
    This is a test.\\
    {\chaptitlefont Chapter title}\\
    {\sectionfont Section font}\\
    \(
    \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1
    \)\\
    \(\mathbf{x^2+y^2=1}\).\\
\verb|Where|
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine on both xelatex and lualatex. I get the following warnings in Lualatex.

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "STIXMathRegular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Math".


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "STIXMathRegular/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).
```

unicode-math still gives the warning that the first font must be an open type math font.
Yet, from the last part of the log file, it seems to be using the STIX Math.

```
<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/inconsolata/InconsolataN-Regul
ar.otf><c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Bold.otf><c:/
texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIXMath-Regular.otf><c:/texl
ive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Regular.otf><c:/texlive/2020
/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Bold.otf><c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist
/fonts/opentype/public/stix/STIX-Regular.otf>
```

In the case of xelatex I can confirm using adobe acrobat reader that  the stix math is used. What is happening?
[image]

If, earlier, if xelatex found STIX Math unusable, how did it become useable after loading latinmodern-math? Why is it still showing these warning messages?

Again, I get the error message

```
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "STIXMathRegular/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).
```

The Mathematics content in bold is printed. I can't detect any font substitution for the bold also. From the last part of the log file produced by lualatex, one can see it is not using any font other than stix or inconsolata. What is happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try with `\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}`  and run with `XeLaTeX` it may help you....

Comment: @MadyYuvi It doesn't work . I still get the warning messages.  By, the way, the first two packages can be used only with xelatex.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. For instance, shouldn't one load the `unicode-math` package before issuing the directive` \setmathfont`?

Comment: Incidentally, instead of writing `\(\mathbf{x^2+y^2=1}\)`, do consider writing `\( \symbf{x}^2+\symbf{y}^2=\symbf{1} \)`. (`\mathbf` draws glyphs from the main text font, whereas `\symbf` draws glyphs from the math font.)

Comment: Just a guess: the math table in STIX is incomplete, compare: `% otfinfo -t /usr/share/fonts/opentype/stix-word/STIXMath-Regular.otf |grep MATH          
   5652 MATH
% otfinfo -t /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xits/XITSMath-Regular.otf |grep MATH
  15910 MATH`. `XITS Math` can be used as a drop-in replacement of STIX Math version 1.

Comment: @Mico, the file compiles fine as it is on my windows machine.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman - You write, "The file compiles fine...". You've posted two code blocks. The first block, which is what I was referring to, does *not* load the `unicode-math` package, and it doesn't compile. Does your latest comment maybe refer to the second code block?

Comment: @Mico.  Yes, I stand corrected.  I have edited my post.  unicode-math loads fontspec. Without fontspec the code will not compile. I missed this point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Khaled Hosny’s XITS and XITS Math are forks of STIX that fix its bugs, and have the same glyphs.  While STIX Two also works as a replacement, it’s a noticeably different font and might meet your requirements.  For example, it will not match the house style of a journal that typesets in STIX.

As a bonus, XITS offers a bold math font, which `unicode-math` loads automatically.  If you use `\boldmath` or `\boldsymbol`, XITS Math will work out of the box.

```
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{XITS}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}
[...]
```

The STIX (one) fonts have the script definition "math" missing in the font. Which is, of course, no real problem: You can ignore the warning. However, using STIX2 makes more sense.