# Problem with xits and \binom command

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

The `\binom` command doesn't work correctly with XITS and unicode-math. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math Regular}
\begin{document}
    \(\binom{2n}{n}\)
\end{document}
```

This is the output I get when I compile the file with LuaLaTeX.
[image]

I am using `TeXLive` 2021.

Comment: This is a problem with the `XITS Math` font. Switching to `\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}` (and `\setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular}` for consistency) fixes the issue.

Comment: The binomial coefficient looks fine with xits when I test in ConTeXt (both mkiv (luatex) and lmtx (luametatex)).

Comment: @mickep This probably just shows my missing ConTeXt skills, but when I tried with `\setupbodyfont[xits]
\starttext
$\binom{2n}{n}$
\stoptext` I got the same result as in LaTeX.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, No, you have the skills, the error was mine. I did the test in display math mode, where it actually looks good. In inline math mode it does indeed look bad with luatex (but it still looks good with luametatex). Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: I did like XITS.  Since there doesn't seem any other way, I have switched to STIXTwo as Daniel has said.  XITS is the complete font and unicode-math supports 2427 symbols. But, unicode-math also supports  2422 symbols from STIXTwo, so it is not so bad.  I like the times-like appearance of XITS though.

Comment: STIXTwo doesn't have bold mathematics fonts either. So, this is a problem too. Can the problem with XITS be fixed? I switched to XITS because of the problem described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550866/problems-in-using-stix-math-with-xelatex-and-lualatex

Comment: What do you expect for bold maths? `\symbf{A}`, `\symbf{Γ}` for instance get printed as expected with STIXTwoMath.  STIX, XITS and STIXTwo fonts are part of the same project: see https://www.stixfonts.org, file a bug report there if needed. `texdoc XITS` points to https://www.stixfonts.org.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other post, I think latin-modern is used whenever bold font is needed.. Unfortunately, in the luatex log, latin-modern font is not mentioned as one of the fonts embedded in the pdf file.   There is no bold math fonts in STIX or STIX TWO.  Only XITS has bold math fonts. So, this is not a STIX bug really.  The log file has this error message: Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "STIXTwoMath/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

Comment: Sorry, your assumption " latin-modern is used whenever bold font is needed" is wrong. You can check with `\showoutput` that the bold Maths symbols come from STIXTwoMath. Most Maths fonts do not have a bold counterpart, the upright, italic, bold and bold italic Latin and Greek letters are included in the regular Maths font.

Comment: @Daniel, may be you are right, but how come XITS has a bold Mathematics font? It is not necessary if all the fonts are in the regular Maths font. XITS would have bold, upright and italic faces included in the regular Math font.  XITS belongs to the same family as STIX and STIX TWO. I am missing something here. Yes, I will try `\showoutput` also.

Comment: Output for bold version using `\showoutput`
....\mathon
....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/10 
....\hbox(4.543+0.0)x3.79497, shifted -3.59961, direction TLT
.....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/7 
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22198 plus 1.111 minus 2.22198
....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/10 +
....\penalty 700
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22198 plus 1.111 minus 2.22198
....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/10 
....\kern0.3 (italic)
....\hbox(4.543+0.0)x3.79497, shifted -3.59961, direction TLT
.....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/7 
....\mathoff

Comment: Output for normal version in `\showoutput`
....\mathon
....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/10 
....\hbox(4.697+0.0)x4.06796, shifted -3.59961, direction TLT
.....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/7 2
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22198 plus 1.111 minus 2.22198
....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/10 +
....\penalty 700
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22198 plus 1.111 minus 2.22198
....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/10 
....\kern0.3 (italic)
....\hbox(4.697+0.0)x4.06796, shifted -3.59961, direction TLT
.....\TU/STIXTwoMath(1)/m/n/7 2
....\mathoff
Both use /m/n, not b or bx

Comment: The bold math font should be used in bold environment. For example, if you have bold titles and have some math formulae in the titles, then ALL math characters must be bolder. It means that operators are bolder, variables are bold, vectors (used bold in normal typesetting) are super-bold etc. This is reason why we need bold math Unicode fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug in the font. You can try to report it.

There is a workaround in LuaTeX if you set different registers `\Umathstackdenomdown` after the font is loaded:

```
\def\corrxits#1{\expanded{\Umathstackdenomdown#1=\the\Umathfractiondenomdown#1}\relax}
\corrxits\scriptstyle       \corrxits\crampedscriptstyle 
\corrxits\textstyle         \corrxits\crampedtextstyle
\corrxits\scriptscriptstyle \corrxits\crampedscriptscriptstyle
```

I did test this using OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[xits] % XITS + XITS math is loaded
\def\corrxits#1{\expanded{\Umathstackdenomdown#1=\the\Umathfractiondenomdown#1}\relax}
\corrxits\scriptstyle       \corrxits\crampedscriptstyle 
\corrxits\textstyle         \corrxits\crampedtextstyle
\corrxits\scriptscriptstyle \corrxits\crampedscriptscriptstyle

$
  %\scriptstyle
  {2n\choose n}, \quad a_{2n\choose n}, \quad {2n\over n}, \quad {2n\atop n}
$
\bye
```

Thanks to Marcel Krüger for reminder cramped styes.